# Is it possible to access semantically connected registers generically?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, avr-gcc

I have an SPI module which has an initializer function:

```
static volatile uint8_t *registerOut, *registerIn, *registerDir;
static uint8_t clock, dataIn, dataOut;

void SpiInit(volatile uint8_t *pRegisterOut, volatile uint8_t *pRegisterIn,
             volatile uint8_t *pRegisterDir, uint8_t pClock, uint8_t pDataIn,
             uint8_t pDataOut)
{
    registerOut = pRegisterOut;
    registerIn = pRegisterIn;
    registerDir = pRegisterDir;

    clock = pClock;
    dataIn = pDataIn;
    dataOut = pDataOut;

    /* access registers */
    *registerOut |= (1<<dataOut) | (1<<clock); /* set dataOut pin and clock as output */

    /* etc. */
}
```

An example call would look like this:

```
SpiInit(&PORTB, &PINB, &DDRB, PB2, PB1, PB0);
```

Now I wonder if there is a way to not having to pass all the registers which are semantically connected (`PORTB`, `PINB` and `DDRB`). I would like to pass only one reference `PORTx` and somehow derive to its connected registers `PINx` and `DDRx`.

Answer (score 0):

[Preprocessor concatenation.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)

```
#define PORTREGS(let) &PORT ## let, &PIN ## let, &DDR ## let

 ...

SpiInit(PORTREGS(B), PB2, PB1, PB0);
```

Comment: But this would only change the call. The definition of `SpiInit(...)` would still have to contain all three registers.

Comment: So then use a macro to fill a `struct` that gets passed.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an index to an array of `struct{volatile uint8_t *registerOut, *registerIn, *registerDir;}` instead.

Then the call becomes `SpiInit(SPIB, PB2, PB1, PB0);` where SPIB is your own constant that is the index to the entry with `{&PORTB, &PINB, &DDRB}`